# Correct notation for unbiased estimate of population variance

Tags: variance, terminology, notation

I've seen the notation $s^2$, ${s}_{n}^2$, and ${s}_{n-1}^2$ used to represent the unbiased estimate of population variance.  Is there a standard notation?

Answer (score 2):

Typically,

$s^{2}=s^{2}_{n-1}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{n-1}$

where $\bar{x}$ is the sample mean, while

$s^{2}_{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{(x_{i}-\bar{x})^{2}}{n}$.

Whatever notation you use, the first formula gives an unbiased estimate of the population variance, while the second formula is not an unbiased estimate of the variance.

Comment: It is a  great answer. an upvote